# How to display and edit hyperlinks in DBGrid in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, datagrid, hyperlink, dbgrid

I use DBGrid to display Hyperlink type field from Microsoft Access database (MDB).
Normally dbgrid displays hyperlink values like "(MEMO)", without editing capablity. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: check this article:
[http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa030105a.htm](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa030105a.htm)
I hope it will help you

Comment: Using this I can display the content of the field, but it doesn't behave as a hyperlink, and shows as a simple text. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: you may use cellclick event, and call ShellExcecute function:
ShellExecute(0, 'open', pchar([fieldname].AsString), nil,nil, SW_Normal);

Comment: In Access, a hyperlink field is a memo field with some kind of special attribute that tells Access to treat it differently than normal fields. I don't believe there's a distinct Jet/ACE hyperlink field. In general, I would recommend against using hyperlink fields at all, as they cause more problems than they solve. If you have control over the schema, determine if you need to store URLs longer than 255 and if so, make it a plain memo, and if not, Text 255. Then you handle executing it in code in your app's user interface.

Comment: Used this, and it worked, although I had to format cell content. Due to some reason hyperlink was not stored as a normal text, but rather something like "www.google.com #www.google.com#". Still now it works, thanks

Comment: "www.google.com #www.google.com#" is how hyperlinks are stored in an Access hyperlink field, which is just a memo field with a flag somewhere that tells Access to display it as a hyperlink. Most Access developers I know avoid use of them. If you can change the Jet database, I'd recommend dumping the hyperlink field in favor of a Text 255 field or a normal memo field.

Answer (score 0):

DBGrid displays values based on field type. If it shows (MEMO) then you probably declared your field in your database as TEXT or something equivalent. Can't remember Access, but in MS-SQL Server you can change field type to varchar and DBGrid will display values as editable text.